# NTP Server Not Working showing init on centos

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, init, ntp

I am trying to configure ntp server on centos 7 instead of ip address its showing INIT while executing ntpq -p command.

my ntp server configuration file.

/etc/ntp.conf

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift

restrict default nomodify notrap nopeer noquery

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Hosts on local network are less restricted.
Allow 10.0.3.0/24 network clients to syncronize time with this server
restrict 10.0.3.0 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap

# Use public servers from the pool.ntp.org project.
# Please consider joining the pool (http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html).
server 2.in.pool.ntp.org
server 1.asia.pool.ntp.org
server 3.asia.pool.ntp.org

includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
disable monitor
 I have have following outputs while executing ntpq -q command
[centos@ip-10-0-3-53 etc]$ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 ntp.your.org    .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 ns3.weiszhostin .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 resolver2.skyfi .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 ntp2.wiktel.com .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
[spryiq@ip-10-0-3-53 etc]$

Port 123 is listening correctly
[centos@ip-10-0-3-53 etc]$ netstat -plnu | grep 123
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
udp        0      0 10.0.3.53:123           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp6       0      0 fe80::10c9:ecff:fe9:123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                -

[centos@ip-10-0-3-53 etc]$ ntpstat
timeout


[centos@ip-10-0-3-53 etc]$ ntpq
ntpq> as

ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1  1255  8011   yes    no  none    reject    mobilize  1
  2  1256  8011   yes    no  none    reject    mobilize  1
  3  1257  8011   yes    no  none    reject    mobilize  1
  4  1258  8011   yes    no  none    reject    mobilize  1
```

I have configured iptables correctly.instead of INIT it should display ip addresses How can i troubleshoot this problem??

Comment: Do you have Internet connectivity?  `ping 8.8.8.8`, etc.?

Comment: yes we have internet connectivity

Comment: have you checked disabled your firewall to test?

Comment: yes firewall is disable